# Laravel 5.4 task scheduler

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have setup scheduler according to the Laravel 5.4 documentation. But it doesn't work.

My **cron job** is:

```
* * * * * php public_html/demo/artisan schedule:run 1>> logs/cronlog.txt
```

app/console/**Kernel.php**:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{    
    protected $commands = [Commands\OverdueTasksNotifier::class,];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('notify:overduetasks')->everyFiveMinutes();
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

app/Console/Commands/**OverdueTasksNotifier.php**:

```
class OverdueTasksNotifier extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'notify:overduetasks';

    protected $description = 'Sends alerts (email, sms) for un-Ready overdue tasks.';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

and the **cronlog.txt** has:

```
    [ErrorException]                         
    Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

and above text repeats every minute.

I ran `php artisan list` and it lists the added command above which is `notify:overduetasks`.

Could someone point me where the error is? I use shared hosting (cPanel).

**----- UPDATE -----**

`debug` enabled and the laravel.log is:

```
[2017-04-29 21:02:02] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' in /home/serverhostcom/public_html/demo/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:284
Stack trace:
#0 /home/serverhostcom/public_html/demo/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(284): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/home/serverhos...', 284, Array)
#1 /home/serverhostcom/public_html/demo/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(764): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->hasParameterOption(Array, true)
#2 /home/serverhostcom/public_html/demo/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->configureIO(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /home/serverhostcom/public_html/demo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(123): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /home/serverhostcom/public_html/demo/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#5 {main}
```

Comment: I think if you use `php-cli` instead of `php` in your cron (cPanel), you can get rid of the `Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` leaking. As per the actual error, you would have to turn on debug and see the `laravel.log`

Comment: I tried with `php-cli`. But now the log doesn't contain anything. It is always blank. I don't know how to enable debug. Could you please let me know how to do that? Anyway if I run `php artisan notify:overduetasks`, it works nicely. Therefore, as far as I can see, it is not coding error.

Comment: In your `.env` file you need `APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: Looks like your problem is the `1` after `schedule:run`

Comment: But this is my cron command: `php public_html/demo/artisan schedule:run >> logs/cronlog.txt`. I removed `1` after seeing another post... But it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it was to be a typo in paths to php and artisan.

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/[USERNAME]/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Now task scheduler runs properly.