# Cron job issue(Task Schedule) in Laravel

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

Same problem schedule cron job,

my kernal.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Log;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    protected $commands = [
      //  \App\Console\Commands\SecondTable::class,
    ];


    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
                  //->hourly();
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Sale\SaleController@sync')->everyMinute();
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

manually running a command-> php artisan schedule:run is working good!

but, cronjob run server is not working correctly,
my cron job code,

```
* * * * * php /laravel project folder/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "same problem"? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Sorry, i have problem on this code. Not working task schedule in Laravel 5.4

Comment: sorry my Laravel version 5.6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your cronjob code, it could be something like this:

```
* * * * * cd path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

It means: every seconds (* * * * *), go to my project folder (cd path-to-your-project), then execute the command (php artisan schedule:run).

The meaning of the last part of the cronjob is explained here: [What is /dev/null 2>&1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508843/what-is-dev-null-21)

Comment: I have run a command in server, like this https://i.ibb.co/6tMzgZR/error.png but, now working. (Laravel 5.4)

Comment: sorry my Laravel version 5.6.4

Comment: You have to type "php" before "artisan" in your cron job (it is missing in the image you linked). You can see it in my response.

Comment: To run your cronjob in the shell while testing you have to remove * * * * * because it is reserved for the crontab

Comment: i have set path crontab in server. Then run a /usr/bin/php7.0 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects folder/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 manually run working good. but, create a shell file in server. run a 5 minutes only cron job excuted. not working i dont know problem.

Comment: Can you copy and paste here your exact crontab (check it typing crontab -e in your shell)?

Comment: Thanks given suggestions, /usr/bin/php7.0 /mnt/hosting/dev/projects folder path/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 this code working good. any reference, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699948/laravel-5-4-task-scheduler?rq=1